# Implementation of Boyer Moore Horsepool algorithm with wildcards

Tags: java, algorithm, full-text-search, wildcard, boyer-moore

I want to implement a generalization of the Boyer Moore Horspool algorithm that takes care of wildcards (match any letter in the word). This means that the pattern `h _ _ s e` would be found two times in this text: `horsehouse`.

I need help to implement this, I cant get deep enough understanding of the algorithm to figure this out by myself, some tips ?

```
int [] createBadCharacterTable(char [] needle) {

        int [] badShift = new int [256];

        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            badShift[i] = needle.length;
        }

        int last = needle.length - 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
            badShift[(int) needle[i]] = last - i;
        }

        return badShift;
    }

    int boyerMooreHorsepool(String word, String text) {

        char [] needle = word.toCharArray();
        char [] haystack = text.toCharArray();

        if(needle.length > haystack.length) {
            return -1;
        }

        int [] badShift = createBadCharacterTable(needle);

        int offset = 0;
        int scan = 0;
        int last = needle.length - 1;   
        int maxoffset = haystack.length - needle.length;

        while(offset <= maxoffset) {
            for(scan = last; (needle[scan] == haystack[scan+offset] ||  needle[scan] == (int) '_'); scan--) {

                if(scan == 0) { //Match found
                    return offset;
                }
            }
            offset += badShift[(int) haystack[offset + last]];
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Edit: Added solution to use _ (underscore) as wildcard. I just added  needle[scan] == (int) '_') as a test in for-loop.

Comment: Is this an assignment? I spotted someone else posting just this question again in Nov 2013! (Before deleting it) If not, then you don't need to open-code it - so just use `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(needle).replaceAll("_", "\\\\E.\\\\Q"));`